# Access client on VPN Container from another container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, openvpn

Good Day,

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I have the same request as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52591578/access-network-in-other-docker-container) post but it does not have a answer and that is why I am asking it again.

I have multiple containers running on a server, but lets assume just the 3 below:

1. Container A running a web service
2. Container B running a Database
3. Container C running a OpenVPN which has access to 2 clients C1(**192.168.100.1**) and C2(**192.168.100.2**)

I would like **ONLY** Container A to have access to the VPN network on Container C (To be able to ping C1 and C2) and not allow Container B (Ot any other container) to have access to C1 and C2.

At the moment, the VPN container is connected to the HOST network, but this is allowing ALL containers to have access to the VPN

This is what I have tried:

**Container A and C**

```
version: '2'
services:
  odoo:
    container_name: container_a
    ports:
      - "8990:8069"
      - "8992:8072"
    tty: true
    external_links:
      - db12
    networks:
      - default
      - vpn_network

  vpn:
      image: dperson/openvpn-client
      container_name: container_c
      cap_add:
        - net_admin
      networks:
        - vpn_network
      read_only: true
      tmpfs:
        - /run
        - /tmp
      restart: unless-stopped
      security_opt:
        - label:disable
      stdin_open: true
      tty: true
      volumes:
        - /dev/net:/dev/net:z
        - ./vpn:/vpn ## This is where the VPN config is

      ## THIS GIVES ACCESS FOR ALL CONTAINERS AND I DO NOT WANT THAT
      # network_mode: "host"

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: postgres_default12
  vpn_network:
    external:
      name: vpn_network
```

**Container B**

```
version: '2'

services:
  db_primary:
    build: .
    image: sudotechodoo/odoo:postgres12
    container_name: db12
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - data_postgres_main:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  data_postgres_main:
    external:
      name: postgres_data12

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: postgres_default12
```

How can I change it so that I can ping C1 or C2 inside container A but not from Container C?

Thank you in advance